# How can I save/archive people's Medium articles complete with comments/replies?

Tags: medium

How can I archive or otherwise save (in any format – PDF, HTML, I don't really care about the specific format) someone's posting/article on Medium, *including* all the comments that were posted in reply to the article?  To put it another way, if I read something on Medium and I want to archive it externally for research purposes and future reference, how can I do it?

I looked in Medium's help but could not find something to help resolve this. If I print to PDF in my browser, I only get the article itself and not the comments.

Medium may not provide a feature to do this directly, but I have to believe there is *some* way to get the data and save it.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Print Friendly](https://www.printfriendly.com) to get the articles as PDFs.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not include the comments to the (random) test article from Medum that I tried. Did I miss an option that is needed to make it work better?

Comment: Don't know why this is downvoted, it is helpful and working indeed! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not including everything properly, for example code blocks are omitted

Answer (score 1):

use Chrome and [GoFullPage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl).
With this extension you can grab web page content as image or PDF.